# Why is this PostgreSQL query table scanning

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3. The database is of all of the medical NPIs (national provider numbers). I have created the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX indiv_provider_business_mailing_address_state_name_string_index
  ON individuals (provider_business_mailing_address_state_name);
CREATE INDEX indiv_provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name_string_index
  ON individuals (provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name);
CREATE INDEX indiv_upper_provider_business_mailing_address_state_name_string_index
  ON individuals (UPPER(provider_business_mailing_address_state_name));
CREATE INDEX indiv_upper_provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name_string_index
  ON individuals (UPPER(provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name));
```

but the query still table scans:

```
Postgres Running
  SELECT npi, provider_first_name,
    provider_last_name_legal_name,
    provider_organization_name_legal_business_name,
    provider_first_line_business_mailing_address,
    provider_second_line_business_mailing_address,
    provider_business_mailing_address_city_name,
    provider_business_mailing_address_state_name,
    substr(provider_business_mailing_address_postal_code, 1, 5)
      AS provider_business_mailing_address_postal_code,
    provider_business_mailing_address_telephone_number,
    provider_business_mailing_address_fax_number,
    provider_first_line_business_practice_location_address,
    provider_second_line_business_practice_location_address,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_city_name,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name,
    substr(provider_business_practice_location_address_postal_code, 1, 5)
      AS provider_business_practice_location_address_postal_code,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_telephone_number,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_fax_number
  FROM individuals
  WHERE ((((provider_business_mailing_address_state_name = UPPER(regexp_replace(?, '\s+', ' ', 'g'))))
    OR ((provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name = UPPER(regexp_replace(?, '\s+', ' ', 'g'))))))
  LIMIT 100
```

Explain output:

```
Postgres Limit  (cost=0.00..400.58 rows=100 width=141)
  ->  Seq Scan on individuals  (cost=0.00..1210010.61 rows=302063 width=141)
        Filter: ((provider_business_mailing_address_state_name = 'PA'::text) OR (provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name = 'PA'::text))
```

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**:

I changed the query as suggested by Craig Ringer (https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118850/7924), but it is still table scanning:

```
Postgres Running
  SELECT npi,
    provider_first_name,
    provider_last_name_legal_name,
    provider_organization_name_legal_business_name,
    provider_first_line_business_mailing_address,
    provider_second_line_business_mailing_address,
    provider_business_mailing_address_city_name,
    provider_business_mailing_address_state_name,
    substr(provider_business_mailing_address_postal_code, 1, 5)
      AS provider_business_mailing_address_postal_code,
    provider_business_mailing_address_telephone_number,
    provider_business_mailing_address_fax_number,
    provider_first_line_business_practice_location_address,
    provider_second_line_business_practice_location_address,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_city_name,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name,
    substr(provider_business_practice_location_address_postal_code, 1, 5)
      AS provider_business_practice_location_address_postal_code,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_telephone_number,
    provider_business_practice_location_address_fax_number
  FROM individuals
  WHERE ((((provider_business_mailing_address_state_name = ?))
    OR ((provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name = ?))))
  LIMIT 100
```

Explain output:

```
Postgres Limit  (cost=0.00..400.58 rows=100 width=141)
  ->  Seq Scan on individuals  (cost=0.00..1210010.61 rows=302063 width=141)
    Filter: ((provider_business_mailing_address_state_name = 'PA'::text) OR (provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name = 'PA'::text))
```

Comment: Because you use OR, even if you find the right values in one index, any other row might match on hte other column. Try to use UNION instead, using each part of the WHERE clause in a separate query.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression indexes aren't used, or usable.

You're indexing an expression that doesn't match what you're querying. The expression is on the *parameter side*, e.g.:

```
UPPER(regexp_replace(?, '\s+', ' ', 'g'))
```

PostgreSQL is constant-folding that based on the substituted parameter into, in the case you've supplied, the literal `'PA'`. Then looking it up against the column `provider_business_mailing_address_state_name`.

If you *intended* to search against the uppercased, trimmed version of the `provider_business_mailing_address_state_name` column, like your expression index implies, you'd have to use the expression in the SQL too, e.g.

```
OR ((UPPER(regexp_replace(provider_business_practice_location_address_state_name, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) = UPPER(regexp_replace(?, '\s+', ' ', 'g'))))))
```

but frankly, in this case I suggest normalizing the data in the table in-place instead of relying on an expression index.

Comment: I'd give +2 for the normalization hint.